# Is there a way to read a .sbt file from a .xml file play framework?

Tags: xml, playframework, sbt, readfile

I am using Play framework 2.5. I am trying to read **'name:'** field in **build.sbt** file from **conf/logback.xml** file.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's possible in logback.xml, would a `conf/logback.groovy` file allow you to do it?

Comment: I'll try and let you know.